# Recognizing a USB keyboard and mouse within Windows after a clean install

Tags: windows-xp, usb, ps2

I am attempting to deploy a ***bare bones*** Windows XP Pro SP3 clean install image across multiple computers.

It has been a success. However, for computers without PS/2 capabilities, I am unable to configure them because the USB keyboard and mouse is not recognized within Windows. However,  I am able to access the boot menu and the BIOS with the USB keyboard on startup.

I have looked in the BIOS (all the computers are DELL, if that helps any), and there is no explicit "Enable Legacy USB" or similar setting, but any and all settings related to USB ports are on. For one computer with PS/2 capabilites, I just plugged in a PS/2 mouse, rebooted, and then, the USB drivers installed automatically.

How can the computers in question recognize the USB keyboard and mouse? These computers do not have PS/2 capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Windows is notorious for being finicky when switching from PS/2 to USB mice and keyboards.  This even can happen when switching from one USB device to another. What is happening is that  Windows is searching for device drivers since it detected a new device and it will check its driver base and Windows Update for more specific drivers than generic USB keyboard and mouse.  This can take a few minutes - and feel like an eternity.  I have seen Windows get stuck when trying to switch from PS/2 to USB though.

If the computer does boot and you are stuck at the login screen, with no kb/mouse capabilities, disconnect both of them from USB.  Wait a few seconds, then connect one device at a time till you see it is recognized.

If the computer does not boot to Windows, there is a BIOS issue or a hardware issue.

Comment: The computer does boot to Windows. I did as you suggested to no avail.

Comment: do you have a spare usb keyboard or adapters to boot with?  Try booting with PS/2 and see if the computers work.  Then try attaching the USB devices

Comment: Yes, and have tried them. Booting with PS/2? There are no PS/2 slots on this computer...or I am misunderstanding you.